Query in Spring boot with PostgreSQL
How to write a native query to get random items for PostgreSQL.
When I use SQL Server, this query runs correctly
@Query(value = "SELECT TOP (:range) * FROM books ORDER BY NEWID()", nativeQuery = true)
List<Book> findRandomBooks(@Param("range") int range);

But when I change to PostgreSQL, it always returns an error:
JDBC exception executing SQL [SELECT TOP (?) * FROM books ORDER BY NEWID()] [ERROR: syntax error at or near "FROM"
  Position: 19] [n/a]; SQL [n/a]


TOP isn’t valid SQL and that’s why it fails. Use LIMIT or FETCH.

Only tag the RDMS you want your answers in. And always consult the official documentation before posting a question.

this looks like a sql server specific query that is not supported by postgres. Maybe you can use something like that:
List<Book> findRandomBooks(@Param("range") int range);```

As mentioned above by @Frank, the TOP & NEWID() are not supported in PostgreSQL and are SQL Server-specific.
Updated code to make it compatible with PostgreSQL,
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM books ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT :range", nativeQuery = true)
List<Book> findRandomBooks(@Param("range") int range);


ORDER BY RANDOM() - random ordering of results, alternative for NEWID().
LIMIT - alternative for TOP.

In case, if you want to make it compatible for both, then you can either create a conditional query for each database or define a custom Hibernate dialect.
